# (Chart.js 3.7.1) How can I always show the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, java, chart.js

[image]

[Chart.js 3.7.1] How can I always show the tooltip?

1. I want to use tootip always show.
2. And the text should be darkened only on today's date.

Like the picture.

plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

This **Chart.js plugin** might also be a good option for your use case. Refer and implement if it is helpful.

**Reference:**

https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels